# SQL: Ride Share data to find 4-week moving average of time to pickup

Tags: sql, oracle

I was asked this question in an interview but I could not answer it correctly.
Here I have 3 tables

1. Driver

- driver_id Unique identifier for a driver
- driver_onboard_date Date on which driver was on-boarded

2. Rides

- driver_id Unique identifier for a driver
- ride_id Unique identifier for a ride that was completed by the driver
- ride_distance Ride distance in meters
- ride_duration Ride durations in seconds
- ride_prime_time PrimeTime applied on the ride

3. Ride_type

- ride_id Unique identifier for a ride
- event event describes the type of event( requested_at, accepted_at, arrived_at, picked_up_at, dropped_off_at)
- timestamp Time of event

Q1. Trend of 4-week moving average of time to pickup (time elapsed between
accepted_at and picked_up at)

I tried the following but didn't seem like it worked.

```
SELECT

TO_CHAR (T1.TIMESTAMP,’WW’) AS WEEK_NUM,

AVG( ( CAST(T1.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) – CAST( T2.TIMESTAMP AS DATE ))*60*24) AS
TIME_TO_PICKUP_MIN,

AVG(AVG( ( CAST(T1.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) – CAST( T2.TIMESTAMP AS DATE ))*60*24) )
OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR(T1.TIMESTAMP,’WW’) ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND
CURRENT ROW) AS AVG_FOUR_WEEK_TREND

FROM RIDE_TIMESTAMPS T1 INNER JOIN RIDE_TIMESTAMPS T1 ON T1.RIDE_ID=T2.RIDE_ID AND
T1.EVENT=’accepted_at’ AND T2.EVENT=’picked_up_at’

GROUP BY TO_CHAR(T1.TIMESTAMP,’WW’)
```

Comment: Would be able to share some sample dataset?

Comment: @Somy This was an interview assignment with no sample dataset. I have provided all the information i was given